# List included in another list in haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell

I want to see if a list is included in another list and extract that list from a list of lists, for example i want to see if `["bc","abc"]` is included in `[["a","b","c","a","b","c","de"],["a","bc","abc","de"],["a","bc","abc","d","e"],....]` and i want to make a list of the lists that contian that particular list like `[["a","bc","abc","de"],["a","bc","abc","d","e"]]` .
for `[["aabbcc","aacc"]]` I want to match only something like this `["cc","aabbcc","aacc"]` or `["c","c","aabbcc","aacc"]` but not `[["ccaabbcc","aacc"]]`.
Can someone help me?

Comment: is `["bc","abc"]` included in `["a","bc","b","abc","d"]`?

Comment: The part about making a list of the lists that match your criteria can be handled by `filter`. For the other part, you need to decide what it means for one list to contain another. Do the items have to appear consecutively in the other list? Do they have to be in the same order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand you want something that cares for the order of the elements in the list

If you DO care the order of elements:

```
import Data.List (subsequences)

included :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
included ls nest = filter (\x -> any (ls==) $ subsequences x) nest
```

TEST:

```
*Main> included [1,2,3,4] [[1,3,4,5,2],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
[[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

If you do NOT care the order of elements:

```
import Data.List (subsequences, permutations, concat)

included :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
included ls nest = filter func nest
  where
    func x = any (ls==) $ concat $ map subsequences $ permutations x
```

TEST:

```
*Main> included [1,2,3,4] [[1,3,4,5,2],[1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]
[[1,3,4,5,2],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the answer to my question in the comments is no,

```
import Data.List

g :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
g a xs = [x | x <- xs, 
              or [and . map (uncurry (==)) $ zip a y | y <- init $ tails x]]
```

Testing:

```
Prelude Data.List> g ["bc","abc"] [["a","bc","a","abc","de"],["a","bc","abc","de
"],["a","bc","abc","d","e"]]
[["a","bc","abc","de"],["a","bc","abc","d","e"]]
```

Comment: When I use the g function for sometring like this ["aacc","aabbcc"] on a list like [["ccaabbcc","aacc"]] it work but I want to match exactly , I want to match only something like this ["cc","aabbcc","aacc"] or ["c","c","aabbcc","aacc"]

Comment: give me your exact call and show which results do you want to get back.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the answer to Will's question in the comments is “no”:

```
import Data.List (isInfixOf)

foo :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
foo needle haystack = filter (needle `isInfixOf`) haystack
```

(Untested.)

Comment: I knew I was reinventing something! I think you mean the answer is "no".